# Error when attempting to identify which button is being pressed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Being new to Android, I am attempting to identify which button is being pressed by outputting `"Hello"` on that button, but I'm experiencing an error when executing the code.

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {

    Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button1 :
                button1.setText("Hello");
                break;
            case R.id.button2 :
                button2.setText("Hello1");
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown button ID");



        }

    }

}
```

The above code returns the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ...

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace so that we know on which line the error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem are your class attributes:

```
Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

You can't call `findViewById` before calling `setContentView` in `onCreate` method. Change your code:

```
Button button1;
Button button2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `findViewById` inside `onCreate`:

```
Button button1, button2;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to instanciate the button inside onCreate methode like that :

```
Button button1 ;
Button button2 ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

the problem was on binding button with it's proper viewId , so these viewIds are inside **activity_main** layout , so findViewById will search inside that layout for these viewIds and all this will be done inside onCreate method